# Problema al crear directorio en SDCard. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file

Tengo el siguiente código, en el que quiero crear un directorio (E4) en la memoria externa SD, sin embargo, cuando lo ejecuto no consigo crearlo, y además quiero que esté en /sdcard/documents/, pero me lo pone en **/storage/emulated/0/**Documents/ y no encuentro esa carpeta por ningún lado

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("isExtStorageWritable", "Can´t write to Ext. Storage");
        return false;
    }
}

//Get the path to the Documents Folder
public static File getStorageDir(String folderName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public documents directory.
    File documents = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    //path will be storage/sdcard/documents/foldername
    File path = new File(documents, folderName);

    Log.e("getStorageDir", path.toString());

    if (!path.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("getStorageDir", "Directory not created");
    }
    else
    {            Log.e("getStorageDir", "Directory OK");
    }
    return path;
}
```

Los errores del LogCat que tengo para comprobar me dan lo siguiente:

E/getStorageDir: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/E4

E/getStorageDir: Directory not created

Lo estoy ejecutando en Android 6.0 (en un Cubot Echo Music), sin embargo ese mismo código si funciona como quiero en un Android 5.0 de Xiaomi. Soy nuevo en Android Studio

Comment: tienes que preguntar por los permisos de escritura de archivos :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para versiones superiores a Android 5.1 es necesario solicitar los permisos en tiempo de ejecución, si el usuario no otorga el permiso solicitado entonces la aplicación no podrá ejecutar el código de manera correcta.

Aquí tienes un poco de información :

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

El mètodo que usas **[Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) es obsoleto** ya no debe ser usado.

**Para crear un directorio en el almacenamiento secundario externo (SDCard) debes hacer uso del mètodo `getExternalFilesDir()`**, ejemplo:

```
File myDirectory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + folderName);
if (!myDirectory.exists()) {//No existe?      
    myDirectory.mkdir(); //Crea directorio.
}
```